# how to focus a particular Row in devexpress

Tags: vb.net

how to focus a particular Row in devexpress

Comment: More details? What grid? Is it even a grid you are using? Did you know that devexpress.com has a lot of help online, including the answer to this same question?

Answer (score 1):

For the ASP.NET ASPxGridView, you can use a server side or client side method called SetFocusedRowIndex.

Check this [help topic](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3723) for more info.

You might find [this code central example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E135.aspx) useful too.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code sets the focused row for a particular `gridview(gv)`:

```
this.gv.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a selectrow method on the xtragrid.  Unfortunately I no longer have access to DevExpress to check that answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bindingsource, you can select a particular row by specifying its index :

```or-tag-here
int selectedIndex = 5;
bindingSource1.Position = selectedIndex;
```